# Django settings module exception

Tags: python, django, exception, environment-variables

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1741, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1735, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1135, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Apache24/htdocs/consult/accounts/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
  File "C:\Apache24\htdocs\consult\clinicenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Apache24\htdocs\consult\clinicenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Apache24\htdocs\consult\clinicenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 87, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Apache24\htdocs\consult\clinicenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 249, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Apache24\htdocs\consult\clinicenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 131, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Apache24\htdocs\consult\clinicenv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Apache24\htdocs\consult\clinicenv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_xml.py", line 179, in _get_type
    if isinstance(o, t[0]):
  File "C:\Apache24\htdocs\consult\clinicenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 213, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Apache24\htdocs\consult\clinicenv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested settings, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I am very new to Python programming. Please help me to resolve this and let me know how to set PYTHON ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE.

this is my settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS =

[

```
'accounts',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django_mysql',
```

]

MIDDLEWARE = 
[

```
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'consult.urls'

TEMPLATES =
 [

```
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['/templates/accounts/'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'consult.wsgi.application'

DATABASES =

{

```
 'default': {
     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
     'NAME': 'suitecaredb',
     'USER': 'root',
     'PASSWORD': 'innovations',
     'HOST': 'localhost',
     'PORT': '3306',
     'OPTIONS': {
        'charset': 'utf8mb4',
    },
           'TEST': {
        'CHARSET': 'utf8mb4',
        'COLLATION': 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    }
 }
```

}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.User"

Comment: You'll have to provide more context if you expect an answer - more specifically, HOW did you get this error.

Comment: Can you post your settings file too?

Answer (score 1):

To open a python terminal with the Django environment set run

```
python manage.py shell
```

Then, for example, a new user can be created  with the **create_user()** helper function:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')

# At this point, user is a User object that has already been saved
# to the database. You can continue to change its attributes
# if you want to change other fields.
>>> user.last_name = 'Lennon'
>>> user.save()
```

The example code below shows how to add a user from a script. Note that you need to replace `'project.settings'` on line 2 with your project name.

`project.setting` points at your project file where installed apps, middleware, templates, etc are specified.

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

super_user = User.objects.create_user(username = 'john',
                                first_name = 'John',
                                last_name = 'Doe',
                                email = 'john.doe@mail.com',
                                password = 'test',
                                is_staff = True,
                                is_superuser=True
                                )
```

More information in the documentation [docs.djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/)

Answer (score 0):

On setting:

> wsgi.py

Check if it is pointing to the right setting path:

> os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "path/to/settings.py")

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following:

1. As mentioned in the above answer, ensure that the following line is present in `wsgi.py`

   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "/path/to/settings.py")
2. Ensure that above path is correct or the mentioned settings file in above line is the actual settings file.
3. Since you are using Pycharm, the above error could because cause of some issue with the Pycharm environment variable. Try `python manage.py flush`.
4. If the issue still persists, have a look at the environment configuration in the Pycharm settings and check for any discrepancy.